# jQuery not working in Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I am tryting to install a facebook slider tab in a friend's blog and I cannot make it work.

This is her blog: http://secretosdeprofe.blogspot.com.es/

And this is the tutorial: http://www.theblogwidgets.com/2013/11/floating-facebook-like-box-widget-for.html

jQuery is installed in the blog (hence the hover Pin it button working on images) but when hovering the mouse over the facebook tab, the widget does not come out

Any ideas why is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `jQuery` variable in a `<script>` (line 1090) element before you add `<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>` (line 1543), at the time when your earlier script block was parsed jQuery hadn't been defined. It's possible with a little extra work to queue something before jQuery is included (as shown [here](http://writing.colin-gourlay.com/safely-using-ready-before-including-jquery/)) but this approach will still require some code after jQuery is loaded in order to be referenced by jQuery's `onReady` listener.